# Higher bid following currency change

Tags: google-ads-api

For a long time my adwords account was working with NIS currency (while 1USD = 3.5NIS). I've decided to transfer my account to USD currency, for this I've opened a new account and copied all campaigns.

I've noticed something very bizarre in my new USD account. Keywords which were placed in the first page with NIS currency now require a much higher bid. For example, a keyword had a 0.82NIS bid (0.24 USD) and had avg. position of 2.8 now requires 1.31$ according to google to enter the first page.
How is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that the most important factor is that your new account has no CTR history, meaning that your quality score tends to be much lower than in your old account.
This in turn leads to higher first page bid estimates.

Your Google account manager *might* be able to change the currency of your old account if you're <s>a big spender</s> an important customer. That way, your bids should stay pretty much the same.